# Import csv with php to mysql and

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

Hi I want to import my  folder.csv to mysql thanks to php. But I need to

> "Check box 'ON' for Replace table data with file"

, but I don't know how.
 This request sql works but I want to transform him to import with php and do something automatic

```
 $commande="mysql -u root -p mydb LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/Programmes/wamp64/www/Importcsv/imports/test.csv' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ";
    exec($commande);
```

So in fact I need thanks to php import my file.csv and I really need "Check box 'ON' to replace table data with file" . My id is a primary key and a.i so I need to have this option to modified my data in each id .

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you make a temporary upload for the specific file, this is the HTML form for the upload:

```
<table width="600">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Select file</td>
            <td width="80%"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Submit</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

the user `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` to grab that file and parse it like this :

the line above line will grab your file and your have to parse it like this (i'll make a function for you):

```
function parseCSV($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]){
    $csv = [];
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); //this will ignore new lines, 
    //meaning that it will jump to the next row at a new line
    foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {//go trough each line with the foreach loop
        $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value, ';');//this will delimit each column of a row by 
    //';'(semicolon) it might aswell be whatever your need it to be
    }
    //use the block below to see if the CSV was parsed within an array
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($csv);
    //echo '</pre>';
    //die;
     return $csv;
}
```

After parsing the file( seeing it within an array) you can check out W33 tutorial on how to insert values within a table
[w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

I hope this helps you!
have a nice day!

Comment: With your code I should be an Insert or update no ? 
I have the connection with my db . With your code you don't really import you use the Insert or update sql request but I want import with this sql request for some reason like more opti and easiest.

Comment: this is indeed an insert what i described, but it is safer to do it this way, you have access to the array that you want to insert and can format each column as you desire(i.e. an amount column might be float/double/string/int and it could have different delmiters like space, or comma or dot)

Comment: I don't know if I need to prepare tis request like an INSERT or just doing a query if u know How I can execute the request it could be nice

Comment: Yeah I understand but when I do the request into phpmyadmin that work so if I can  write a simply request to import I will appreciate

Comment: try this out [http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/ ]